# Maven home directory not specified - Windows 7 & IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Maven runs on Netbeans just fine.  I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't like IntelliJ.  I've done some Googling and can't figure out what's wrong.  I've read things about specifying a path in my environmental variables, but I have no idea what my "maven install path" is.

[image]

I have followed these instructions which are listed on [Maven's Download Page](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)...

**Windows 2000/XP**

1. Unzip the distribution archive, i.e. apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.zip to the directory you wish to install Maven 3.0.4. These instructions assume you chose C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation. The subdirectory apache-maven-3.0.4 will be created from the archive.
   Add the M2_HOME environment variable by opening up the system properties (WinKey + Pause), selecting the "Advanced" tab, and the "Environment Variables" button, then adding the M2_HOME variable in the user variables with the value C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.4. Be sure to omit any quotation marks around the path even if it contains spaces. Note: For Maven   2.0.9, also be sure that the M2_HOME doesn't have a '\' as last character.
2. In the same dialog, add the M2 environment variable in the user variables with the value %M2_HOME%\bin.
   Optional: In the same dialog, add the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable in the user variables to specify JVM properties, e.g. the value -Xms256m -Xmx512m. This environment variable can be used to supply extra options to Maven.
3. In the same dialog, update/create the Path environment variable in the user variables and prepend the value %M2% to add Maven available in the command line.
4. In the same dialog, make sure that JAVA_HOME exists in your user variables or in the system variables and it is set to the location of your JDK, e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_02 and that %JAVA_HOME%\bin is in your Path environment variable.
5. Open a new command prompt (Winkey + R then type cmd) and run mvn --version to verify that it is correctly installed.

Comment: Where did you install Maven? Note that for me, at least, setting the Maven environment variables doesn't work anyway, I still have to set it manually (both under OS X and Linux).

Comment: I didn't think I needed to.  It works with Netbeans out of the box, I assumed it worked with IntelliJ as well.

Comment: It doesn't include its own Maven, it uses whichever one you specify. (Which is ultimately better anyway, since you can use different versions depending on the project, which matters sometimes.)

Comment: @DaveNewton Unfortunately that didn't resolve anything :-\

Comment: So you still get exactly the same error message when you explicitly select the home directory in the dialog box?

Comment: Yep, I've tried rebooting my PC and everything

Comment: I'm a little skeptical; if that's truly happening you should open a support ticket with JetBrains. I can't reproduce this on multiple machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had downloaded the source, not the binary.  Once I downloaded the binary it worked fine.